# OOP design principles that fit with Unity

Tags: unity, oop

So my current concept is top-down arcade style game. Meaning you have a character and you walk around a closed space killing waves of enemies coming at you. My question is how to structure my abstractions. Since I'm using Unity3d at the end of the day there must a  MonoBehaviour component that exist in the scene. For example I can have the following structure for the character.

```
public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    ICharacter _character;
    IInputController _inputController;
    //and so on
}
```

Is this a good idea at all ? Unity3d doesn't really cater to normal OOP practices imho. I know this question can be flagged as opinion based but please find it in your heart not to. I want to figure out a pattern to write good and easily extensible code in unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity does cater for that sort of abstraction, however you have to do some additional work to leverage it.

In my current project I have series of characters that can be controlled by the player or by AI, so I wanted to abstract their control.  So I created a base class derived from `MonoBehaviour` that looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class CharController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector3 movementVector = Vector3.zero;

    [HideInInspector]
    public Quaternion lookAtRotation = Quaternion.identity;

    public float moveSpeed = 250.0f;
    public float turnSpeed = 1.0f;

    protected Rigidbody _rigidbody = null;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _rigidbody.AddForce(movementVector * moveSpeed);
        _rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(_rigidbody.rotation, lookAtRotation, turnSpeed);
    }
}
```

Which is standard Unity except for the use of `protected` and `virtual` on the standard methods.

Here is an example of a specialised version of this class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SpecialCharController : CharController
{
    protected override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();

        // Special stuff here    
    }

    protected override void FixedUpdate()
    {
        base.FixedUpdate();

        // Special stuff here    
    }
}
```

Note the use of `protected`, `override` and calls to `base.Method()`.

The `PlayerController` and `AIController` scripts only need to find and communicate with the `CharController` script in order to control all of the characters and the specialised version of the characters will work just fine.